# Azure DevOps - Publish Universal Package:

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 1 events with X-TFS-Session error

An error occurred on the service. User  lacks permission to complete this action

To publish the artifact by using Universal Publish in AzureDevOps Pipelines.

We need to push the artifact from the Pipelines to Artifact in AzureDevOps